# Google maps api wont display full map

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load a google map via their API v3 into a hidden container.
The width and height of the container are explicitly set in the css.

However the map wont display to the full width/height:
[image: Google maps api wont load full width]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a FAQ. call

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

before showing the map.